# React Native problem with Image.getSize function

Tags: react-native

I am new with React Native, so be patient my friends. I have been struggling with getting the image size outside of the `Image.getSize` function.

First problem: Console is logging first `console.log('Image.getSize funktion ulkopuolella koko on ${imgWidth} x ${imgHeight}')` while there is `Image.getSize` before that. Tried re-order them with no luck. And it's logging image size `0x0`.

I want use those `width` and `height` for drawing image. But I do not know how to "get them out" from the `Image.getSize` function. How I can do it?

The point in this function is to get image size for calculating right image ratio for resizing.

```
kuvanpiirto = () => {

                    pdfKuvaKorkeus = 100;

                    let imgWidth = 0;
                    let imgHeight = 0;

                    Image.getSize(arr[i].path, (width, height) => {
                        console.log(`Kuvan leveys PDF luonnissa on  ${width}`) // logittaa kuvan leveyden
                        console.log(`Kuvan korkeus PDF luonnissa on  ${height}`) // logittaa kuvan korkeuden



                        imgWidth = width;
                        imgHeight = height;

                    });

                    console.log(`Image.getSize funktion ulkopuolella koko on ${imgWidth} x ${imgHeight}`) // logittaa kuvan leveyden

                    if(imgHeight>imgWidth) { // VERTICAL / PYSTYKUVA
                        page.drawImage(arr[i].path.substring(7),'jpg',{
                            x: imgX,
                            y: imgY,
                            width: pdfKuvaKorkeus*1.33,
                            height: pdfKuvaKorkeus,
                        })

                    }
                    if(imgHeight<imgWidth) { // Horizontal / Vaakakuva
                        page.drawImage(arr[i].path.substring(7),'jpg',{
                            x: imgX,
                            y: imgY,
                            width: pdfKuvaKorkeus*0.75,
                            height: pdfKuvaKorkeus,
                        })
                    }

                }
                kuvanpiirto();
```

Tried also put all code inside Image.getSize function like this:

```
kuvanpiirto = () => {
                    Image.getSize(arr[i].path, (width, height) => {

                        imgWidth = width;
                        imgHeight = height;


                        if(imgHeight>imgWidth) { // VERTICAL / PYSTYKUVA
                            console.log(`Vertical - IMAGE SIZE ${imgWidth}X${imgHeight}`)
                            console.log(`IMAGE PATH ${arr[i].path}`)

                            page.drawImage(arr[i].path.substring(7),'jpg',{
                                x: imgX,
                                y: imgY,
                                width: 100*1.33,
                                height: 100,
                            })
                        }
                        if(imgHeight<imgWidth) { // Horizontal / Vaakakuva
                            console.log(`Horizontal - IMAGE SIZE ${imgWidth}X${imgHeight}`)
                            console.log(`IMAGE PATH ${arr[i].path}`)

                            page.drawImage(arr[i].path.substring(7),'jpg',{
                                x: imgX,
                                y: imgY,
                                width: 100*0.75,
                                height: 100,
                            })
                        }
                    });
                }
                kuvanpiirto();
```

It works better, but not draw an image. Giving error, picture below. Do not have any glue why it cannot draw the image.
[image]

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't check but it should work

```
kuvanpiirto = async () => {
  // your code
  
  const {imgWidth, imgHeight} = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    Image.getSize(img, (width, height) => {
      resolve({imgWidth: width, imgHeight: height});
    });
  });

  // your code
};
```

Comment: It throwing error: `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: width`

Comment: Throw error again: `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'page.drawImage')`. Console logged `{arr[i].path}` but somehow it is empty when ap trying to draw image.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect ( ()=>{
Image.getSize(uri ,(width,height)=>{
setWidth(width)
setHeight(height)
}
},[uri])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).